# Can we pull data in servicenow ui from a external data source/api?

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

Can we pull data in servicenow ui from a different data source/api?

Comment: Yes. But your question does not provide any detail on what you want to do and what you have already tried. ServiceNow supports many integrations out of the box and provides tools to build custom integrations through a variety of data sources.

Answer (score 0):

A few options

Load script to import set
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/paris-platform-administration/page/administer/import-sets/reference/custom-type-data-source.html

Remote Table
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/rome-servicenow-platform/page/administer/remote-tables/concept/remote-tables.html